# Error in rep.int(names(value), lapply(value, length)) : invalid 'times' value

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data.frame which has about 25,000 rows. It has one column 'cig30br2' which contains a set of 88 values, for the 25,000 rows. Basically, it can be thought of as 88 levels. I am trying to rename the levels from their original numeric format to words.

To do that I have created another csv file where the first column are the numeric levels and the second columns are the words to be used for those levels.

I have used mapvalues and was getting the following error when trying to run it:

> "Error in rep.int(names(value), lapply(value, length)) :
> invalid 'times' value"

Tried a number of options, but nothing seems to be working. What does this error exactly mean?

Please find the code below:

```
# Loading NSDUH
NSDUH<-PUF2019_100920
NSDUH_cig30<-subset(NSDUH_1_cigever,select=c("cig30br2","cigever"))

NSDUH_cig30 <- NSDUH_cig30 %>%
  mutate_all(as.factor)
class(NSDUH_cig30$cig30br2)

# Reading in the levels file and naming the first column as old and the second as new
cig_brand<-read.csv("cig_brands.csv")
old<-cig_brand[1]
new<-cig_brand[2]

# Coercing old and new to lists
old=as.list(old)
new=as.list(new)
#Applying mapvalues, to try to change all the numeric levels in NSDUH_cig30_sub$cig30br2 from the old list to the new list
NSDUH_cig30_sub$cig30br2<-mapvalues(NSDUH_cig30_sub$cig30br2,from = old,to=new)
```

The warning is:

> The following `from` values were not present in `x`: c("102", "104", "105", "107", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "125", "126", "128", "130", "132", "141", "142", "144", "147", "149", "158", "160", "161", "175", "178", "179", "183", "402", "404", "423", "492", "527", "810", "832", "1001", "1008", "1018", "1020", "1029", "1040", "1041", "1064", "1083", "1086", "1092", "1112", "1139", "1221", "1227", "1268", "1276", "1277", "1296", "1308", "1313", "1317", "1318", "1324", "1335", "1344", "1346",
> "TOBACCO", "Codebook Creation Date: 10/9/2020 ", "1349", "1359", "1361", "1376", "1412", "1420", "1421", "1998", "1999", "3999", "4455", "4999", "5999", "8999", "9000", "9991", "9993", "9994", "9997", "9998")
> and the error i am getting is : Error in rep.int(names(value), lapply(value, length)) :
> invalid 'times' value

Comment: Sorry, but to provide a full answer, we need a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: But I'd like to suggest that you take lookup `left_join` from `{dplyr}`, or maybe `merge`, and join on the factor that you're trying to convert back into.